# JavaScript Multi Select Box not posting all items

Tags: javascript, php, forms, multi-select

I found a nice demo on an old JSFIddle for Moving items from one multi-select box to another with JavaScript

You can see the demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/e6Y7J/25/

The problem is, the visual part works correctly but when I put this on a server with PHP, it only `POST` the last item added to the new select box.  So instead of POSTING an array of items, it will only `POST` 1 item regardless of how many items exist in the selection box.

Can anyone help me?

The JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.siblings('select').append($this.find('option:selected')); // append selected option to sibling

    });   
});
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes

Comment: As a form, it's normal for a select to only have one value. If you need multiple items to be sent to the server, consider using checkboxes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've hit this issue before.  For the PHP $_POST array to populate this correctly you need to add a name field with [] at the end of the name.  PHP will then interpret the result as an array of all the values and not just the last selected one.

Example:

```
<select name="demo_multi[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

When you recall the item in the $_POST array leave off the square brackets.

```
$values = $_POST['demo_multi'];
```

Comment: I had to dig this up a couple weeks ago myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the multiselect name to an array

```
<select name="post_status[]" multiple id="select2" class="whatever" style="height: 500px; width: 222px;"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also have to select all items in the 
This is pre jquery but it works.

```
`<form onsubmit="selectAll();"> ....</form>
function selectAll()
{
    for(j=0; j<document.formdata.elements.length; j++)
    {
    // if a multiple select box then select all items in the box so they are sent with the form
    var currObj = document.formdata.elements[j];
        if (currObj.tagName == 'SELECT' && currObj.multiple == true)
            for (i=0; i<currObj.length; i++)
                currObj.options[i].selected = true;
    }
}`
```

This will then be loaded into the array named in the